# what are the differences between the batch parameter in the yolov3.cfg and the batch_size parameter in the keras.fit()?

Tags: keras, computer-vision, yolo, darknet

What are the differences between the `batch` parameter in the `yolov3.cfg` file and the `batch_size` parameter in the `keras.fit()`? How should I set them? please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference, batch size means how many images (samples) will be in a mini-batch while training. For yolo, usually in the inference case, the batch_size is 1.

How would you set it?
Go for as high as you can unless you run out of GPU memory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,then I just need to set the batch_size parameter in the keras.fit(), not need to set the batch and subdivisions in the  the yolov3.cfg file ?Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, keras has no subdivision.

Answer (score 0):

Batch size is a term used in machine learning and refers to the number of training examples utilized in one iteration.

Traditionally, batch_size are chosen as a power of 2 -> 8, 16, 32, 64. The higher the batch size the faster the convergence usually.

Comment: well,you may not understand what I mean，but thanks for your answer